# Bevel + Subdivision modifier error and crease edges

Tags: edges, subdivision-surface, bevel

I have a problem with the combination of these two modifiers.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried every combination but similar "artifacts" appears on various position when I use bevel and subdivision surface modifiers in combination.

Online I read that the bevel modifier is not that great and many people advices to use the crease tool.
The problem is that the creased edges will disappear when exporting the model in obj or stl format....

How can I solve this problem? I would like o avoid to add edge loops because the topology would turn more complex

Comment: For starters you could try **Limit Method: None** in your Bevel. If you still have artifacts at >= 2 segments, I'd suspect problems with topology, like doubles (A, M, B in edit mode to merge them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to do is to apply scale (ctrl A) and disable clamp overlap in the bevel modifier. Also set the shape under profile to 1 and reduce the size of the bevel till it fits.

Next you can try to use weighted bevels to have more granular control. Select all the edge loops (its important that its the full loop otherwise it may create artifacts as well) that are supposed to be sharp and hit ctrl E -> Edge Bevel Weight and pull your mouse out till it turns blue. Also switch the limit method to weight in the Bevel modifier.

I am curious tho, why you dont want to use edge loops specifically? Using a bevel modifier is the same thing, just in a different way.

Hope it helps

Comment: I need to precise that I'm a newbe.
When I model something and then add edge loops, often the topology of the model becomes very confused... using a modifier, I only need to look in the settings panel and I can change the parameters more easly

However, the method you suggested to me seems to have partially solved the problem
But isn't using Edge Bevel Weight the same thing as edge crease?

Comment: No. Creases... idk how they work, they shouldnt be used. Bevels and edge loops are superior. Edge Bevel Weight tells the modifier where to apply the bevel. This ensures bevels are going the whole loop. Wit the angle method a few edges may be missed leading to bad topology and potential artifacts